# Smooth scrolling is not constant in performance on all devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my practice page I have a smooth scrolling function which seems to work fairly well. The code for it is below.

```
$(function () {
     $('a[href*="#"]').click(function () {
        var $target = $(this.hash);
        $target = $target.length ? $target : $('html');
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, {duration: 1500, easing: 'easeInOutCubic'});
        return false;
     });
});
```

When I have been testing it on different devices I have noticed a slight discrepancy which could affect other functions in the future. When my scroll script is activated on some devices it will scroll to where it is meant to. However on a few devices it will scroll to a point which is slightly lower than where it is meant to scroll. This will leave a small strip of maybe only one or two pixels of the previous section. To fix this I normally might add or minus 1 or two pixels from the target position like I did in the script below.

```
$(function () {
     $('a[href*="#"]').click(function () {
        var $target = $(this.hash);
        $target = $target.length ? $target : $('html');
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top + 1;
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, {duration: 1500, easing: 'easeInOutCubic'});
        return false;
     });
});
```

The problem with doing it like this is as I stated before the problem does not affect all devices and I don't know what makes the devices work differently except maybe the screen size/resolution.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/64zy15te/) with the code in use.

I would appreciate any help in fixing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that it might be lagging.

You should use a library such as **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)** (in this case with the [ScrollTo](http://greensock.com/ScrollToPlugin) plugin) for better performance. jQuery is known to have bad animation performance, and animating the scroll position can be particularly expensive.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example of how to use the scroll to plugin

Comment: @Dan I'm going to do one as soon as I can (which might not be very soon...)

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes on this question and wonders how I managed to get it to work the final script is below. I made it using the GSAP plugin, [ScrollToPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/ScrollToPlugin/), as [gcampbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6303733/gcampbell) suggested

```
$(function () {
    $('a[href*="#"]').click(function () {
        if(this.hash != "") {
            TweenLite.to(window, 1.5, {scrollTo:{y:$(this.hash).position().top, autoKill:true}, ease: Power2.easeInOut});
        } else {
            TweenLite.to(window, 1.5, {scrollTo:{y:0}, ease: Power2.easeInOut});
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```